# About parsing XML document in Python using ElementTree (findall method)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm starting to learn about parsing XML documents in Python. Below are my code (the XML document is inside too)

```
input = ''' <stuff>
    <users>
        <user x="2">
            <id>001</id>
            <name>Chuck</name>
        </user>
        <user x="7">
            <id>009</id>
            <name>Brent</name>
        </user>
    </users>
</stuff>'''

stuff=ET.fromstring(input)
print(stuff.findall('stuff')) #Show blank list
print(stuff.findall('users')) #Show list with 1 value
print(stuff.findall('user')) #Show blank list
print(stuff.findall('users/user')) #Show list with 2 value
print(stuff.findall('stuff/users')) #Show blank list
print(stuff.findall('stuff/users/user')) #Show blank list
```

May I ask why `findall` `'stuff' 'user'` and `'stuff/users' 'stuff/users/user'` show blank list? When I worked with HTML using beautifulsoup everything was fine, then when I learn XML with ElementTree this happens.

Comment: `findall()` finds children (and deeper descendants). `stuff` is the root element, It doesn't have any descendants called `stuff`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So everything starting with stuff won't work. May I ask that I also can't directly access the children tag, right? (for example findall('user'))

Comment: You can do `findall('.//user')`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax